# What's wrong with this SQL query?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT [travel], [fro_m], [t_o], [dep], [arr], [fare], [discount], [faresleeper],
[rating], [seats], [s_no],
[booking_closed] = 
   CASE WHEN s1from <= @date AND s1to >= @date THEN s1Rate ELSE fare END 
        WHEN s2from <= @date AND s2to >= @date THEN s2Rate ELSE fare END 
        WHEN s3rate <= @date AND s3to >= @date THEN s3Rate ELSE fare END 
FROM a1_volvo WHERE (fro_m = @fro_m) AND (t_o = @t_o)
```

Comment: What did you find wrong with it? Is there an error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case statement is incorrect:

```
CASE WHEN s1from <= @date AND s1to >= @date THEN s1Rate 
WHEN s2from <= @date AND s2to >= @date THEN s2Rate 
WHEN s3rate <= @date AND s3to >= @date THEN s3Rate 
else fare END
```

You have and else statement after each line in the case statement.  It should only be at the end.

[MSDN Case Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

In the third `WHEN` option you are comparing a field with name `s3rate` with a date .Well I dont know what these fields are but it seems to me that is not a date field...

Also have a look at [Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478121/whats-wrong-with-this-sql-query/4478140#4478140) & [BobTodd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478121/whats-wrong-with-this-sql-query/4478149#4478149) answers for another catch...

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE WHEN s1from <= @date AND s1to >= @date THEN s1Rate 
        WHEN s2from <= @date AND s2to >= @date THEN s2Rate 
        WHEN s3rate <= @date AND s3to >= @date THEN s3Rate 
    ELSE fare 
END
```

is better?

Answer (score 0):

This does the same as his code, but uses between and. They advantage of using it is, that it is better readabl. When doing code review you spare endless time compare whether two name are typed identical

```
 CASE WHEN @date between s1from AND s1to THEN s1Rate 
      WHEN @date between s2from AND s2to THEN s2Rate 
      WHEN @date between s3rate AND s3to THEN s3Rate 
      ELSE fare 
END
```

Comment: **Note:**
If I could use code formating in comments, I would have posted this as comment to BobTodd and not as my own answer. I think he answered the question and most best practice hints should go into comments