# How to write the SQL Server query for this?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
SELECT 
   [travel], [service], [bus_type], [travelid], [fro_m], [t_o], 
   [dep], [arr], [booking_closed], [discount], [faresleeper], 
   [rating], [seats], [s_no], 
   s1from, s1to, s1rate, 
   s2from, s2to, s2rate, 
   s3from, s3to, s3rate,
   [fare] = CASE 
               WHEN @date BETWEEN s1from AND s1to THEN s1rate 
               WHEN @date BETWEEN s2from AND s2to THEN s2rate 
               WHEN @date BETWEEN s3from AND s3to THEN s3rate 
               ELSE fare 
   END 
FROM 
   a1_volvo 
WHERE  
   ( fro_m = @fro_m ) AND ( t_o = @t_o )
```

the query mentioned above will show the different fare on between different dates ...

```
fare = textbox1.text   
date = label1.text (shows todays dates)
zero =label2.text
```

**Date Slot 1**

```
s1from = textbox2.text (choose date here 01-May-2011 )
s1to=textbox3.text ( choose date here 30-May-2011)
s1rate = textbox4.text ( rate between s1from & s1to ) say 400
```

**Date Slot2**

```
s2from = textbox5.text (choose date here 01-jun-2011 )
s3to=textbox5.text ( choose date here 30-Jun-2011)
s2rate = textbox7.text ( rate between s2from & s2to ) say 500
```

**Date Slot 3**

```
s3from = textbox8.text (choose date here 01-Jul-2011 )
s3to=textbox9.text ( choose date here 30-Jul-2011)
s3rate = textbox10.text ( rate between s3from & s3to ) say 600

if user select date between s1from - s1to then fare= s1rate
if user select date between s2from - s2to then fare= s2rate
if user select date between s3from - s3to then fare= s3rate
```

- If any user enter the date before s1from date then show actual fare
- If any user enter the date after s3to date then label2.text will be shown

How to write the select query in this case ..

Comment: Are all these questions yours: [What's wrong in this query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220669/whats-wrong-in-this-query), [whats wrong in this query ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231310/whats-wrong-in-this-query), [What's wrong with this SQL query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478121/whats-wrong-with-this-sql-query)?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    [travel], [service], [bus_type], [travelid], [fro_m], [t_o],
    [dep], [arr], [booking_closed], [discount], [faresleeper],
    [rating], [seats], [s_no], s1from, s1to,
    s1rate, s2from, s2to, s2rate, s3from, s3to, s3rate,
    CASE
        WHEN @date < s1from THEN fare
        WHEN @date BETWEEN s1from AND s1to THEN s1rate
        WHEN @date BETWEEN s2from AND s2to THEN s2rate
        WHEN @date BETWEEN s3from AND s3to THEN s3rate
        ELSE NULL
    END AS [fare]
FROM a1_volvo
WHERE
    ( fro_m = @fro_m ) AND ( t_o = @t_o )
```

It's not clear what you want to return in case the date is after `s3to`, I just put `NULL` because it's easy to test for. Also if you do the case logic in SQL then you probably don't need to return all the values involved in that logic (`s1from`, `s1to`, `s1rate`, `s2from`, `s2to`, `s2rate`, `s3from`, `s3to`, `s3rate`)

Comment: Yes, I've been told that before :c)